# PID of the background function, F, in commands invoked in subshells inside F

Tags: bash, process, background-process

When `foo` is run in the background, the `BASHPID` of `foo` (`bashpid_of_foo`) is not available inside the bodies `bar_1` to `bar_n` via `$BASHPID`, since they get invoked via the Command Substitution feature of `bash`:

```
function foo() {
    local bashpid_of_foo=$BASHPID
    local output

    # desired to be shared by all Command Substitutions
    # in the body of this function.
    local log=/path/to/log.$BASHPID

    ... >> $log

    output=$(bar_1 ...)
      ...
    output=$(bar_n ...)
}

function bar_1() {
   # log only specific (and NOT all) messages
   # to the shared log file of the invoking thread.
    ... >> /path/to/log.$BASHPID
}

foo &
foo &
```

**Question:** Is there an elegant way around the above limitation, without having to pass `bashpid_of_foo` via adhoc environment variables or external disk files?

By *elegant*, I mean, being able to keep the interfaces and bodies of `bar_*` functions clean by relying only on bash-provided features. (Eg `BASHPID` is a `bash` feature.)

If I try to override the value of `BASHPID`, like this,

```
out_1=$(BASHPID=$BASHPID bar_1 ...)
```

... it (rightly) complains about `BASHPID` being a readonly variable.

**EDIT:** (1) Added the definition of `bar_1` above. (2) Added the 2nd call to `foo` in the background. Each `foo` invocation needs to maintain its own log file, since writing to a common file could result in garbled contents.

**NOTE:** Whatever logging happens in the runtime context of `foo`, I want it to go into the `foo`-specific log file, `/path/to/log.$BASHPID` **WITHOUT** passing around the name of this log file or even the PID of `foo`. `foo` can have multiple instances running in the background.

Comment: `BASHPID` may be special, but `bashpid_of_foo` is not. You should be able to use that in the command substitutions.

Comment: @Harry If you save `$BASHPID` in `bashpid`, then the only thing you have to do differently in your command substitutions is to _not press shift_ when typing `bashpid`.

Comment: These are the types of best practices or tricks you have to resort to @Harry as Kusalananda is saying by keeping complex software in Bash.

Comment: @Kusalananda *"then the only thing you have to do differently in your command substitutions is to not press shift when typing bashpid"* Lol that was astute! Ok, bro.

Comment: My boss was pressuring me to write my script in Java (yuck!). This is a customer's server - it has Java and `bash`, but no Perl, Python, Ruby, etc. I fought with him to let me do it in `bash` since I'm mostly using `/bin` and `/usr/bin` commands - coding which in Perl, Python, and Ruby can be relatively more verbose than `bash`. And now I run into this dead-end - which I *can* surely workaround (like you suggested) but would've preferred not to (by relying some existing facility. Btw, I feel, this is a feature-flaw in `bash`: A `bash` function (and, not an external program) should be allowed +

Comment: to be invoked either in a subshell (as it is now), or in the context of the current shell, say, via `$$(command ...)` or some such syntax. I'm disappointed... it's not like I'm asking for closures or monads here Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

bar () {
    # bashpid is set in our environment from the calling function
    printf 'bar BASHPID = %d, bar bashpid = %d\n' "$BASHPID" "$bashpid"

    # in your case, you would have...

    local logfile="/some/path/to/log.$bashpid"

    # etc.
}

foo () {
    local bashpid="$BASHPID"
    local message

    local logfile="/some/path/to/log.$BASHPID"

    message=$( bashpid="$bashpid" bar ); printf 'Message from bar: %s\n' "$message"
    message=$( bashpid="$bashpid" bar ); printf 'Message from bar: %s\n' "$message"
    message=$( bashpid="$bashpid" bar ); printf 'Message from bar: %s\n' "$message"
    message=$( bashpid="$bashpid" bar ); printf 'Message from bar: %s\n' "$message"
}

foo &
foo &
foo &

wait
```

Example run:

```
$ bash script.sh
Message from bar: bar BASHPID = 71979, bar bashpid = 18461
Message from bar: bar BASHPID = 7420, bar bashpid = 71036
Message from bar: bar BASHPID = 6109, bar bashpid = 18461
Message from bar: bar BASHPID = 27868, bar bashpid = 71036
Message from bar: bar BASHPID = 44547, bar bashpid = 60086
Message from bar: bar BASHPID = 69310, bar bashpid = 71036
Message from bar: bar BASHPID = 37649, bar bashpid = 60086
Message from bar: bar BASHPID = 15999, bar bashpid = 71036
Message from bar: bar BASHPID = 81520, bar bashpid = 18461
Message from bar: bar BASHPID = 92568, bar bashpid = 60086
Message from bar: bar BASHPID = 72438, bar bashpid = 18461
Message from bar: bar BASHPID = 15094, bar bashpid = 60086
```

For each invocation of `foo` in the main part of the script, four calls to `bar` will be made and four lines of output will be produced.  As you see, there is only three unique `bashpid` numbers, each from one of the `foo` invocations.

Another way of passing `$bashpid` from `foo` to `bar` is obviously to pass it as a command line argument and to receive it with `local bashpid="$1"` in `bar` or something similar, but you say you don't want to do this.

Comment: The `bashpid` approach should work for me. But if `bashpid` is the local/dynamic scope of `foo`, why are you passing it as an env var when calling `bar`?

Comment: @Harry It allows for the case where `bar` is a script or other application (not a function).

Comment: Then, can't we just `export` it from within `foo` so that ALL calls to functions or programs/scripts from within `foo` automatically get it, instead of I passing it explicitly every time?

Comment: @Harry Yes, of course, if you wish to do it that way. However, that would also set it in `foo` and in whatever environment `foo` is executing in. In this case, you are running `foo` as a background job, so it doesn't affect the other `foo`s or the main script.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** *In regards to your general questions around `$BASHPID`, this is readonly and you cannot manipulate it. This is by design.*

*It's typically my general advice that when you get to the level of sophistication with Bash scripts like this, it's time to move it to Python, Ruby, whatever.*

---

#### Your example

I guess I don't see what your issue is, this works for me:

```
$ cat subby.bash
#!/bin/bash

function foo() {
    local bashpid_of_foo=$BASHPID
    local output=blipblop

    echo "foo: $bashpid_of_foo"
    echo "foo: $output"
    out_1=$(echo $bashpid_of_foo)
    out_n=$(echo $output)
    echo "out_1: $out_1"
    echo "out_n: $out_n"
}

foo &


$ ./subby.bash
foo: 4900
foo: blipblop
out_1: 4900
out_n: blipblop
```

#### Addition of export

If we change this around by making `bar_1` into a shell script:

```
$ cat bar_1
#!/bin/bash

echo "from bar_1: $bashpid_of_foo"
```

And change your original script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo() {
    export bashpid_of_foo=$BASHPID
    local output=blipblop

    echo "foo: $bashpid_of_foo"
    echo "foo: $output"
    out_1=$(echo $bashpid_of_foo)
    out_2=$(./bar_1)
    out_n=$(echo $output)
    echo "out_1: $out_1"
    echo "out_2: $out_2"
    echo "out_n: $out_n"
}

foo &
```

We can see that the `$bashpid_of_foo` is getting exported properly to subshells:

```
$ ./subby.bash
foo: 5014
foo: blipblop
out_1: 5014
out_2: from bar_1: 5014
out_n: blipblop
```

We need to use an `export` here and not just a `local` because otherwise the environment variables will not get exported to any children. The subshells are child shells here.

```
$ help export
...
   Marks each NAME for automatic export to the environment of subsequently
    executed commands.  If VALUE is supplied, assign VALUE before exporting.
```